# How exclude a file?

Tags: java, maven

I have maven project. I need compile this project for test and for production.

production should not contain private.key file. I excluded it like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>license/private.key</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>parking.application.Starter</mainClass>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

project don't have maven profiles. Should I create profiles for this little exception or there are another way?
and If I have to create profiles, how do I do this without repeating too much code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found only one solution use invalid property for profile and real for default

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>privateKey</id>
        <properties>
            <exclude.private.key>none</exclude.private.key>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<properties>
    <exclude.private.key>license/private.key</exclude.private.key>
</properties>
```

---

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${exclude.private.key}</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>parking.application.Starter</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

run for production: mvn
run for test: mvn -P privateKey

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `packagingExcludes` parameter. Something like this:-

```
<configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>META-INF/abc.xml</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
```